# vb Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im new to the razor syntax and im struggling to correctly escape back to html when in code.

Here is an example that I can't get working

```
@For Each item In Model
Dim currentItem = item
@<tr>

    <td>
        <video controls poster="@currentItem.ImageName + ".jpg" width="320" height="240">
        <source type="video/flv" src="@currentItem.VideoName + ".flv"">
        </video>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Id)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Name)
    </td>


 </tr>
Next
```

I have tried using  and @:. But the razor syntax keeps complaining. Would really appreciate having my code fixed with an explaination of why the new code works.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it right. The only problem is the definition of the paths.

What you basically need is the following:

```
<video poster="[image name].jpg" ...>
```

where `[image name]` is replaced with the correct value. So you need `@currentItem.ImageName`. That is correct. You can end this expression with a space. However, this will add the space to the output, which is not desired here. Instead, you can define the end of the expression with brackets: `@(currentItem.ImageName)`.

So your definitions would be:

```
<video controls poster="@(currentItem.Day).jpg" width="320" height="240">
    <source type="video/flv" src="@(currentItem.Month).flv">
```